What does "Replace All" do in YouTube Studio?
I want to use YouTube Studio's "Replace all" feature to replace a word in multiple video titles. I expected there to be two fields, the text to replace and what to replace it with, but to my surprise there was only a single field.
What does the "Replace all" edit type do in YouTube studio?


"Replace all" is not a "Find and Replace" option.
"Replace all" will overwrite the specified field in all the selected videos with the whatever text you enter.
There isn't a "Find and Replace" tool.  The closest thing would be two seperate options "Remove" followed by "Insert at [beginning, end]".
This would be adequate if the word(s) you want to swap is at the start or end of the text. Otherwise you will need to do it manually or presumably a script that uses the API would have more options.
